# Login URL to login into environment hub. Please suggst

Tags: environment-hub, developer-org

i tried to find the login URL for environment hub and failed in that. Can someone please shed some light on this? I am able to access the developer instances that i had created using environment hub. Now, i want to add one more developer org and i know using environment hub it is possible. But i forgot the login url or the path to access environment hub. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/environment_hub_manage_connect_org.htm) what you're looking for?

Comment: Environment hub is an Appexchange app installed on an org (need to request it from SF support). This should be your regular org. What exactly are you missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. In Salesforce, go to the app launcher and choose Environment hub.
2. Open the record corresponding to the org you want to login to OR click Create Org from them Environment Hub tab.
3. Click the "Login" button on the record.